# Трафик по пользователям

Tags: сеть, windows, трафик

В локальной Windows-сети есть порядка десятка пользователей. Все они выходят наружу через роутер. Кто-то активно смотрит видосы. Как или чем отслеживать, кто сколько трафика потребляет?

Comment: Роутер в Вашем случае реализован аппаратно или программно? Если программно, то на какой ОСи? Если аппаратно, то какая модель используется? Если модель роутера не профессиональная, то есть ли возможность поставить еще одну машину в качестве прокси?

Comment: Это аппаратный роутер типа DLink DIR-632. Да, свободные машины есть, наверное, их можно поставить как прокси.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поднять прокси сервер, например [SQUID](http://www.squid-cache.org/). К нему есть [документация на русском](http://squid.h12.ru/FAQ/FAQ.html). Установить его Вы сможете на любой машине, как с Windows на борту, так и с *nix.

Comment: 1. squid (бесплатный)2. usergate (платный)их надо будет установить на какой-либо машине в локалке (отдельную выделять не обязательно)в самом DIR-320 надо создать правило перенаправления пакетов на 80 порт на машину с прокси-сервером (но при этом разрешить обращаться самому прокси-серсеру напрямую в интернет). Браузер можно настроить на прокси автоматически, используя специальный url настройки прокси или при помощи скриптов, выполняемых при загрузке. Подробнее надо?

Answer (score 1):

Должен уточнить предыдущего отвечавшего. У каждого пользователя на машинке должен быть настроен браузер на ваш прокси-сервер.Я бы предложил (если действительно нужно считать трафик) на простенькой машине поднять роутер под линукс, поставить iptables, принудительно переадресовывать пакеты на squid (это называется прозрачный прокси). Но при этом будет считаться только трафик WWW, а почта, например, считаться не будет. Если нужно серьезный подсчет, а знаний линукса нет - можно поставить фронт-энд систему учета (фантомас, например).Справедливости ради должен отметить, что под вин аналогичные программы тоже есть, но они платные

Comment: вовсе необязательно на каждом ПК прописывать прокси, к тому же такой прокси можно обойти (просто отключив его использование). При грамотной настройке squid + firewall прокси можно сделать прозрачным. А заодно в настройках squid прописать какой-нибудь фильтрующий dns-сервер(например, skydns). Для 10 компов не вижу смысла поднимать отдельный сервер. У меня дома с этим неплохо справляется и Dir-320.